# Question About move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2003

I used to have a php file that does a simple move_uploaded_file by using selecting a local file and upload to our UNIX web server.

Now we migrate our code to a Windows2003 Server, then the move_uploaded_file() fails, the error that keeps coming up reads like:

"Cannot move the C:Windows\temp\100D.php" file to desiredDirectory.

here desiredDirectory means it caputures the correct directory for this file movement. The code we used is pretty straightforward:

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target))

and we did try change it to $HTTP_POST_FILES, but still not working.

So we are really clueless at the moment, wonder if any experts could give us some hints, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the target directory exists and if the apache user has all rights on that folder.

For a test you can set the folder access settings for the user 'everyone' to 'full'

The snippet of your code i see here is correct and you don't have to use $HTTP_POST_FILES

Answer (score 1):

Does the webserver have write permissions on the target directory? Given that you say the paths are correct, that's the other #1 major reason why file moves fail.